# Fullscreen HTML5 Section Background Video

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I tried to make Full screen HTML5 Section Background Video with css and HTML5 and found many articles, but not all with same concept.

The problem is that all the articles make the video with  `position: fixed;` that make the video scroll with you. I need to found a way to make the video in the first section in the site only like [this site](http://riskeverything.us/).

The General Concept is :

http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

**HTML :**

```
<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**CSS :**

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

i make live example to test ur comments please check [here](http://mohammadsamy.com/Video/)

Comment: try `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: @Aditya its make the video smaller . sorry Not working

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the video inside a div like this and increase z-index of content,let me know if this works..

```
    #video_container {
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
     min-height: 720px;
    }
   #bgvid {
     min-width: 100%;
   }

<div id="video_container" style="overflow:hidden; background-size:cover;">
    <video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
       <source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
 </div>
```

Comment: sorry @Aditya , still the video fixed :( but the scroll is show and i can scroll the content up the video :D

Comment: i uploaded it in my server please check 
http://mohammadsamy.com/Video
, i found another problem the height:720px; cut the video ?

Comment: :( can you try it in the live example . the red dive become top

Comment: Try giving height accordingly ,please upvote/accept the answer if helped you..thanks

Comment: Why its not work in Chrome ? its give me black screen

Answer (score 0):

try the code of @aditya with an

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

on the container